# Socket.io - Is it possible to pass callback functions as parameters in a socket emit event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to pass callback functions in a socket.emit event? The reason I'm asking is I would like to pass some data as a parameter ONLY IF it has been uploaded in the form. To be more specific, a user can create a status that allows him to upload an image and a string of text IF he wants to but it is NOT REQUIRED. Is something like this possible...

```
 // Client side code
 socket.emit('an event', required_data, function(){
   if(the string of text was included)
   {
      pass it as a parameter in the socket emit event
   }
 }, 
 function(){
    if(the image was included)
    {
      pass it as a parameter in the socket emit event
    }
 });
```

If anyone can offer some advice on how it can be done it would be appreciated. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not realy sure what you want but as for an answer to your question title i would say yes you can have a callback to socket.emit like this

CLIENT :

```
socket.emit('event', data, function(response){
    do something
})
```

SERVER :

```
socket.on('event',function(data, fn) {
    // do whatever
    fn(response)     // callback of emit
})
```

Here whatever value you put as parameter 'response' in fn(response) would be available in clientside callback.

Comment: What I am trying to do with the function being passed on the client side, is pass an additional parameter containing data only if the user sends it. So if he wants to upload an image, the function will say, 'if there is an image that has been uploaded, pass it along to the node server.' Any ideas on how this can be done? I'm a little confused.